# WordPress enqueue scripts on admin subpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to enqueue a css and js file on a specific admin page.
The targeted page is wp-admin/users.php?page=bp-profile-edit. For that I'm trying:

```
function my_enqueue ( $hook ) {
    if ( 'users.php?page=bp-profile-edit' == $hook ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(  ) . 'myscript.js' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(  ) . 'mystyle.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

It works only on users.php, not on the targeted page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) or simpler just use the $_GET param.

So:

```
function my_enqueue ( $hook ) {
    if ( 'users.php' == $hook && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] == 'bp-profile-edit' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(  ) . 'myscript.js' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(  ) . 'mystyle.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`users.php?page=bp-profile-edit` is not a correct hook suffix. Hook suffix is a sanitized string of request string. So the correct `$hook` should be `users_page_bp-profile-edit`. You can find out more about `$hook_suffix` [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/admin.php#L192).

This should work:

```
function my_enqueue( $hook ) {
    if ('users_page_bp-profile-edit' === $hook) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'myscript.js' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'mystyle.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Also, [`__FILE__`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) is a required parameter in `plugin_dir_url()`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for the tip on the __FILE__ parameter. Both your solution and kindisch worked.